# GUI button not responding through script reference?

Tags: unity-game-engine, onclick, uibutton

So I'm making a pause menu and for some reason, the button doesn't respond when I click by showing my UI panel. I even set it up fine in the Inspector- OnClick(). It displayed the function and everything so why won't it show?

```
public static bool GameIsPaused = false;

public GameObject pauseMenuUI;
public Button yourbutton;
public bool buttonIsClicked;



void Start ()
{
    Button btn = yourbutton.GetComponent<Button> ();
    btn.onClick.AddListener (TaskOnClick);
    buttonIsClicked = false;
}


// Update is called once per frame
public void TaskOnClick ()
{
    if (buttonIsClicked) {
        if (GameIsPaused) {
            Resume ();
        } else {
            Pause ();
        }
    }

}


public void Resume ()
{
    pauseMenuUI.SetActive (false);
    Time.timeScale = 1f;
    GameIsPaused = false;

}

public void Pause ()
{
    pauseMenuUI.SetActive (true);
    Time.timeScale = 0f;
    GameIsPaused = true;
}

public void LoadMenu()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene ("GameScreen");
}

public void QuitGame()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene ("GameScreen");
}
```

}

Comment: do you have an EventSystem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anywhere that buttonIsClicked is set to true, so it seems that nothing would ever happen in the click handler.

Comment: Thank you I was wondering if it was that. What I did was said the button is clicked= true; and Pause();

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a breakpoint in the method and start debugging.
Also check your Raycast Enabled property in Сanvas and in Image component in Button, there should be check